# testing angular services with mocha

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mocha.js

I've been trying to unit test some angular js services **using Mocha** by injecting mock dependencies. I've read a lot about this and there is some suggestion that using the master branch of [angular-mocks](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/639786083151ff93d70d31332bad143483140de0/src/ngMock/angular-mocks.js) should work fine with mocha. However, when I try this, I get the follwing javascript error and the 'inject' and 'module' functions are undefined:

`ReferenceError: beforeEach is not defined`

I've also tried using angular.injector, which has led me to some success, however, I am unable to mock the services which my service depend on (in this case $http). My service:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap'], function($provide){
    $provide.factory('myService', ['$http', function($http){
        return { 
            doSomething: function(batch){
                ...
            }
        };
    }]);
});
```

Resolving:

```
$injector = angular.injector(['ng', 'app']);
var subject = $injector.get('myService');
```

Is this possible without using jasmine?

Answer (score 0):

The angular-mocks shipped with all AngularJS versions < 1.2.0 is not compatible with mocha. Use the bower version of angular-mocks instead: https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-mocks